# Jquery resize document height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I'm having a little trouble with my jQuery/JS code.

Whenever the window resizes, the "stretch" function should be run.

Now, I tried this:

```
function stretch() {
    var stretch_elem = $('.stretch');
    if (stretch_elem.length) {
        var h = $(document).height() - stretch_elem.offset().top - 70;
        stretch_elem.height(h);
    }
}

$(window).resize(stretch);
```

But something strange is happening, when I resize the window. The element I'm stretching is just getting longer and longer, even if I upsize the window and the document height is getting lower.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/9fcLs7ru/) of what I think your code might be like. What should happen when you resize? Do you want your element's width or height to be proportional to the window?

Comment: I have an grey background colored area that I want to stretch so it reaches the footer, which is at the bottom of the document at all times. Now, when i resize, the grey area becore 16k px in height, even when i upsize the window

Comment: It sounds like we need more info about how the footer and grey background is set up. Can you make a complete [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your setup?

Comment: Just fixed it. Had to add `stretch_elem.height(0);` before setting the new height. Didn't think I needed to do that. But it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed it. Had to add `stretch_elem.height(0);` before setting the new height. Didn't think I needed to do that. But it's working now.