# $(window).height keeps growing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to dynamically resize part of a webpage but the section only kept growing, even when the window's height was reduced. So I logged height and got something strange.

This is the function which should resize (the idea is that each one of the three section of this class should occupy the whole screen, forcing the user to scroll down to get to the next one):

```
function set_section_min_height(){
    var newHeight = jQuery(window).height();
    console.log("Window: " + newHeight);
    console.log("Section: " + jQuery(".pgsc_frontpage_section").height());
    if(newHeight > jQuery(".pgsc_frontpage_section").height()){
        jQuery(".pgsc_frontpage_section").height(newHeight);
    }
}
```

The function is called when the document is ready and at each resize:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){set_section_min_height()});
jQuery(window).resize(function(){set_section_min_height()});
```

This is my log after *reducing* the window's height

```
Window: 972
Section: 150
Window: 3356
Section: 972
Window: 10508
Section: 3356
Window: 31964
Section: 10508
Window: 96332
...
```

It goes on until I get:

```
Window: 33554431
Section: 33554428
```

Comment: How is your function set_section_min_height() called ?

Comment: I edited the question to add the calls

Comment: Well when you set the height, wouldn't that bump the content down making the window height larger?

Comment: I had a similar problem once. Fixed it and posted my solution here, hope it can help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926391/jquery-resize-document-height

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the use case you described, you probably don't need (or want) jQuery for this. The CSS unit `vh` would serve you well.

```
.pgsc_frontpage_section {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

This will set the height of the div to the full height of the screen.

Comment: And what happens if the section's content is bigger? I want to be sure I'll not lose anything.

Comment: @frollo In that case you can set `min-height: 100vh;`

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the height of the section to be the height of the window. By doing this, both the section and the window grows. By doing that repeatedly, it is always growing.

If you want to use the full size of the window use CSS:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

Or:

```
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
```

If you only want the height use:

```
height: 100%;
```

Or:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes. And why do you expect it not to grow?

Each time you encrease height of subitem, everiting outside of it doesn't change its size, so the total size grows. And you repeat it forever.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Blazemonger, this is the answer.